# Hide tag and category boxes from the post editor

Tags: categories, tags, post-editor

I want to hide the tag and category boxes from the post editor, the theme I've just developed doesn't need them, thus I want to hide them.

I am aware they could be hidden using the 'screen options' menu, however I'd prefer to do this with a bit of code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`remove metabox`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function you can do this. Simply put this inside your themes `functions.php` file at very end.

*NOTE - unwrap `<?php` `?>` if necessary.*

```
<?php 
function wpse60590_remove_metaboxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag' , 'post' , 'normal' ); 

}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpse60590_remove_metaboxes' );
?>
```

Comment: glad, I could help.

Comment: I don't think this works in the Gutenberg editor.